# Understanding EOSIO voting mechanism and decay

Tags: eosio-code, voting, eosiocpp, eosio.system, vote-decay

I have a question on eosio-voting and decay. Suppose there are only 21 block-producers (registered) and only 10 users having equally eos-token. These users now voting for each block-producers, it mean each block-producers have equal scale of total_voting. So now all 21 block-producers starts to produce block according to eosio-scheduling.

Now my question is if these users stop to voting (each voter votes first time for 21 block-producers only), then what happened ?

1. Does these 21 block-producers stop producing blocks (as vote-decay)
2. Does this decay only, which they re-vote otherwise not ?
3. Is voting power effect, if user doesn't vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, voting weight increases rather than decay. If user doesn't change vote (even voting same producers is counted as new vote), voting weight is not changed, not increased by temporal multiplier. However, voter who has same amount of staked EOS but changes his vote, he will get increased voting weight in every week. Relatively, we can say unchanged voting weight is decayed.

1. No. Voting decay doesn't reduce weight on each producer. They are kept as same value.
2. Re-vote will calculate new voting weight by multiplying increased factor with staked EOS.
3. New voting weight is calculated when user changes his vote. It's not accumulated process, so you can have full voting weight ( not decayed) any time if you change vote.

Comment: If all user of eosio stop voting then what will happen, block-producers stop producing blocks or not ?

Comment: No, voting is condition for changing block production schedule. The last production schedule will continue.